# dynamic library for windows 7

Tags: c#, dll

I'm trying to create a dynamic library (.dll) to put my own functions so I can use them on other c# projects.

I'm running Visual Studio Community 2017 on Windows 7 x64.

When I start a new project and the .dll option the VS only allows me to create it for Windows 10 and if I accept it tells me I need to  have Windows 10 installed (of course).

I already searched the VS installer for options for Windows 7 but I can't find any. Is there any package I'm missing or is there a way to go around this?

Comment: Visual Studio does no such thing. You never select an OS - there's no such option. You select only the target runtime version and bitness (ie AnyCPU, x86, x64). Perhaps you *aren't* creating [a class library project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/library-with-visual-studio)? What project did you create?

Comment: I select Class Library for Universal Windows, then a menu pops up asking me the target version and minimum version. On these options I get Windows 10 only

Comment: Wrong project. Universal Windows is for UWP applications only. Check the link

Comment: Thank you @PanagiotisKanavos!